# Как вызвать CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть `CustomValidator` к примеру:

```
protected void CheckAge_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     if (//условие)
     {
         args.IsValid = false;
         CheckAge_CustomValidator.ErrorMessage = "Error!";
     }
     else
         args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Нужно вызвать валидатор в `Page_Load()` и нужен результат выполнение валидатора
Если Валидатор заработал то выполнить действии
 Попробовал так:

```
  if (CheckAge_CustomValidator.IsValid == false) //если заработал и показывает ошибку
  {
      //-------
  }
```

Comment: Думаю, надо вызвать ```validator.Validate();```

Comment: @tym32167, где вызвать? как это будет в условии

Comment: перед проверкой на ```IsValid ```

Comment: дока тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validate(v=vs.110).aspx